# In Pine Script, my buy and sell signals lag the ma crossover on the chart

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I know this a very basic code, but I'm confused as to why when I plot the 12 and 36 period ma, it will show a crossover, but the buy and sell signal will not occur for 2-3 bars afterward.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © ChickFilATrader

//@version=4
strategy("Moving Average Cross", overlay=true)

ma1 = ema(close, 12)
ma2 = ema(close, 36)

long_entry = crossover(ma1, ma2)
short_entry = crossunder(ma1, ma2)

if (long_entry)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    
if (short_entry)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)

plot(ma1)
plot(ma2)
```

I'm expecting that the buy and sell signal will occur on the close of a bar where the ma cross

[Example of what I am seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnOAU.png)

Answer (score 0):

In pinescript strategy, during historical bars, values are evaluated once the bar is closed.
If the entry condition occur during a bar, the trade will be placed at the close of this bar.
And your trade will be shown at the opening of the next bar.
This is why you think trades occur 'after'.

To reduce this you can work on a smaller timeframe and calculate your ema from a superior timeframe.